# How to Create Textbox with Dashed Border or Double Line Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to create the following two textboxes (NOT rectangles) in XAML or C# code

[image: Textboxes with border]

Comment: You mean in XAML or in code-behind? You say WPF or c# code, WPF isn't code, it's part of the framework... clarify a bit. My guess is that you want to redefine the control template..

Comment: @Charleh We can create shape in C# code as well. Like Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); rect.Height = ... I mean either way will be fine for me. Thank u.

Comment: Image is gone, so this is now no longer an answerable question, or useful for other visitors as they can't see if their problem matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Blend to edit the control template for text box. I did it for double boder for you.

```
 <Style x:Key="DashedTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5">
                         <Border BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1" BorderThickness=".5">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and apply it on text box like.

```
<TextBox Text="Hello world" Width="100" Height="30.667" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="90" Style="{DynamicResource DashedTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

You may need to customize it for more better look. Also I have removed default border from style.

You can do same for your dashed one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur code,but I have an error for **Value 'ScrollViewer.PanningMode' cannot be assigned to property 'Property'. Invalid PropertyDescriptor value** I do not have blend. Did u include something in the header just like **xmlns:something="something"**

Comment: There are other errors: **error MC4005: Cannot find the Style Property 'IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'**, **error MC4005: Cannot find the Style Property 'IsSelectionActive' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'.** Could u give me the whole xaml. Anyway, this is really the formal way to achieve my goal. Thanks

Comment: Any tutorial for using blend for setting border as **style** only. I would like to go with this way to fill several *styled* border in **resource dictionary**

Comment: @dongx, you can just remove above two lines which are giving you compilation error. You need to understand the [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx). and how to edit the control template in expression blend. Just google it. You will find the real good articles for this.

Answer (score 11):

You could use rectange to create the "Dash" style

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Width="200" Height="40" Name="Textblock1" Text="Hello World!" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=Textblock1, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=Textblock1, Path=ActualHeight}" StrokeDashArray="0.0 6.0 0.0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

And for double line you could possibly create 2 borders

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" Width="200" Height="40" BorderThickness="1">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" Margin="2" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock  Name="Textblock1" Text="Hello World!" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]